# How do I update the menuitem name in custom listview to sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, listview, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I am new  to using sqlite databases. I have created a database as a test. And table as test. In test table I created two columns one is `key_id` another one is `menuname`.

I inserted some `menunames` in test table along with key_id. I have then fetched `menunames` from sqlite database to custom listview using simplecursor adapter and then append to edittext:

[image]

The url contains my output screen shot. If I changed some `menunames` in edittext after click menu button in android it means it shows save button. If I click save button means what are I am edited menu names is replaced by old `menunames` or using `key_id`:

How do I update the menuitem name in custom listview to sqlite database in android?

I tried this code:

```
         public class EditMainMenu extends Activity {
private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editmainmenu);
    ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    final Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text };

    EditMainMenuListview adapter = new EditMainMenuListview(this,
            R.layout.editmainmenulistview, cursor, from, to);

    listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("gouthampra");
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.save, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.save:

        break;
    case R.id.back:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
 }
```

EditMainMenuListview.java

```
              public class EditMainMenuListview extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

Cursor c;
Context context;
Activity activity;

public EditMainMenuListview(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.c = c;
    this.context=context;
    this.activity=(Activity) context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.editmainmenulistview, null);
    View row = convertView;

    c.moveToPosition(position);

    EditText menuname = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

  menuname.setFocusable(true);
    menuname.setText(c.getString(1));


    return(row);
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and better explain what you're trying to do.